# design approach for multiple control signals

Tags: led

I built an LED driver based on TI's [LM3549](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3549.pdf), to drive an RGB LED. It works great, but requires that I provide a control signal for each LED:

[image]

In my testing, I'm using an Arduino to generate the control signals, and am effectively tying up the run loop with with the operation. If it were a single line, I could use a hardware timer, but I don't want to (or have) 3 timers to tie up this way. Is there a more cost-effective way to create this kind of control signal, without dedicating an MCU to it?

Comment: You should look to see how the Servo library works, it can run up to 12 servos using a single timer. You can take a similar approach since it looks like the control lines are just 3 PWM signals.

Comment: @RonBeyer I thought about it, but the issue is that I need the signals to be strictly sequential, whereas the servo library doesn't care... though you did just give me an alternate idea.. i can have it wake on a timer, determine what should be lit, and bring that high... hm...

Comment: Wait, no, that doesn't work. It would either require me to trade off color spectrum against MCU load.

Comment: "I'm using an Arduino" - which Arduino?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Pro Mini. That's running a 328P @ 8MHz / 3.3V

Comment: "Is there a more cost-effective way to create this kind of control signal, without dedicating an MCU to it?" - not sure what you mean by this. Do you want to use the Arduino but without tying up all the CPU time on the LED driver, or do you want to control the LED driver with a separate circuit ?

Comment: @BruceAbbott either of those, hence the wording. I'm looking for options.

Comment: Just use one timer and write you own ISRs that vary the count value each time they run. You'll have to control the hardware directly though, the arduino direct pin manipulation functions are far too slow